# SQL Replication with multiple servers using public IP?

Tags: sql-server, network-programming

I'm trying to replicate from SQL Server 2014 to other SQL Server 2014. I can't add subscribers with SQL Login, and I'm getting this error.

> Sql Server replication requires the actual server name to make a connection to the server. Connections through a server alias, IP address or any other alternate name are not supported. specify the actual server name

Note: I'm not change original server name

Can anyone help me how resolve Public IP to name? Or how can make VPN between two servers VIA Public IP ?

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone help me how resolve Public IP to name??

On each server add a hostname entry for the netbios name of the other server in `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`, or add the entries the DNS that each server users.